# How can I implement backtracking for a climbing stairs practice in JS?

Tags: javascript, dynamic-programming, backtracking

I am having trouble implementing backtracking in a function. I have a question taken from code fights that I [will link here](https://codefights.com/interview-practice/task/cAXEnPyzknC5zgd7x).

> You need to climb a staircase that has n steps, and you decide to get some extra exercise by jumping up the steps. You can cover at most k steps in a single jump. Return all the possible sequences of jumps that you could take to climb the staircase, sorted.
>
> For n = 4 and k = 2, the output should be:
>
> ```
> climbingStaircase(n, k) = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2]]
> ```

I am supposed to come at this problem with a backtracking mindset, but backtracking is new to me and I am having a hard time implementing it in a function. I feel like I am on the verge, but just need a little push. How can I solve this and fully understand backtracking?

Comment: I bet better title will be a good start ?

Comment: Have a suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

I was stuck in the same problem, but I solved it. here is the solution in Java:

```
    ArrayList<int[]> solutions = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    int[][] climbingStaircase(int n, int k) {
        climb(new int[n*k], 0, 0, 0, n, k);
        return trimSolution(solutions);
    }

    void climb(int[] sol, int index, int step, int sum, int max, int stepMax) {
        if(step != 0) {
            sum += step;
            sol[index++] = step;
            if(sum < max) {
                // printArray("it: ", sol);
            } else if(sum == max){
                // printArray("sol: ", sol);
                solutions.add(trimSolution(sol));
                sol[--index] = 0;
                return;
            } else {
                sol[--index] = 0;
                // printArray("failed: ", sol);
                return;
            }
        }

        for (step = 1; step <= stepMax; step++) {
            // System.out.println("index: " + index);
            climb(sol, index, step, sum, max, stepMax);
        }
    }

    int[] trimSolution(int[] sol) {
        int length = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sol.length; i++) {
            if(sol[i] != 0)
                length++;
        }
        int[] r = new int[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
            r[i] = sol[i];
        }
        return r;
    }

    int[][] trimSolution(ArrayList<int[]> sol) {
        if(sol.size() == 0)
            sol.add(new int[0]);
        int[][] r = new int[sol.size()][1];
        for (int i = 0; i < sol.size(); i++) {
            r[i] = sol.get(i);
        }
        return r;
    }

void printArray(String message, int[] a) {
    System.out.print(message);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Dumping code is not helpful, please explain it. Sometimes, code is just proof that someone has an internet connection; explanation shows you understand the answer yourself, and are considerate enough to explain it.